# Xdebug - Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

[image: phpinfo]

[image: can not config error]

[image: Debug config]

[image: validation on xdebug]

> Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression `isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])`

In xdebug.ini file

```
  zend_extension=xdebug.so
  xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.profiler_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
  xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
  xdebug.remote_autostart=1
  xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

can i configured wrong ...

I am using Ubuntu, PhpStorm, Xdebug

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Show `phpinfo()` output, interested in other `$_SERVER` variables. It's possible that you have server name empty there... (if so, you nee to configure your Apache better)